# Convert to srtftime

Tags: python, mysql

```
SELECT_NO_PROCESSED_QRCODES = "SELECT id, visit_date, added_in_monitoring FROM locations_qrcode " \
      "WHERE DATE_FORMAT(visit_date, '%Y%m%d') = %(value)s"
```

This SQL works perfectly outside a python (def) function.
Is this because of MySQL's `DATE_FORMAT` that stops working because it is inside a Python function?

My visit_date field is a datetime field, I need to use `strftime` within SQL to convert to ('% Y-% m-%d), how can I do this?

like: `strftime(visit_date,'% Y-% m-% d')`

Comment: The python syntax to format the date would be - `visit_date.strftime(% Y-% m-% d)`, where `visit_date` is a `date` or `datetime` object.

Answer (score 0):

1370 (42000): execute command denied to user 'erico'@'%' for routine 'visit_date.srftime'

user - password and database is ok

```
def process_qrcodes():
    now = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    while True:

        try:
            cur = conn.cursor()
            #QRCODES = "SELECT id, added_in_monitoring, string FROM locations_qrcode WHERE added_in_monitoring='0'"

            now = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            NON_PROCESSED_QRCODES = "SELECT id, added_in_monitoring, string FROM locations_qrcode " \
                                    "WHERE visit_date.srftime('%%Y-%%m-%%d') =%s" % (now,)

            cur.execute(NON_PROCESSED_QRCODES)
            results = cur.fetchall()
            for result in results:
                idqrcode = result[0]
                string = result[2]
                process_status_qrcode(idqrcode, string)
                print("OI")

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        time.sleep(10)
```